# Compatibility of SharePoint 2010 and IE10

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

We use here IE9 as default. Next time we want eventually step further to IE10. I read something about Problems with the People-Picker and the preview of Excel files.

Did **you** have any experience with this combination?

Answer (score 1):

You can press F12 to bring up the developer tools and then try changing both the Browser Mode and Document Mode.

In particular, try changing the browser mode to Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility View and the document mode to Internet Explorer 8 standards.

[For more information see this link](http://gigajim.com/blog/2012/12/11/sharepoint-2010-and-ie10-incompatibility)

Answer (score 0):

in this article you can read the different levels of Web Browser Support by SharePoint: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx#browserdetail

This is a nice thread about the IE10 compatibility: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/d806c08b-ec61-4639-9798-3e16a81c58e2

Answer (score 0):

I had various strange problems when using IE 10 which turned out to be caused by a bug in the original release of the ASP.NET 2.0 framework on my SharePoint web-front-end servers.

It's pretty obvious if you have this particular issue, it causes various problems such as:

- Sometimes the 'edit page' button in the page ribbon does not respond. If it does, the save buttons is not visible and does not respond
- Save buttons in item edit dialog boxes do not respond (e.g. adding a calendar appointment)
- Unable to use datasheet view
- Unable to add user to a site
- Problems Downloading an Excel workbook
- Problems adding a document to a library
- Problems with editing item properties
- 'Open with Explorer' mode on libraries
- Uploading multiple documents window
- Using Windows and Forms authentication
- Problems using Excel web access web part

The root problem is not with SharePoint (which makes this VERY difficult to troubleshoot) but with the original release of ASP.NET 2.0 (which SharePoint runs on top of) which, [as explained by Scott Hanselman in this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) contains a bug in the 'browser definition file' which reads the UserAgent HTTP header sent by user's browsers to detect what browser the user is using. It can't interpret the new UserAgent string sent by IE 10. This has the knock-on effect that SharePoint also doesn't know what the user's browser is, hence all the JavaScript problems.

To verify, check your version of ASP.NET 2.0 on your WFE, or by firing up IE 10, press F12 to bring up the developer tools, and force the User Agent string (not the compatibility mode!) to IE 8 to see if that fixes the issue.

If it does, you need to apply the hotfix to ASP.NET which updates the browser definition files (see KB2600100).